Maximum update depth exceeded react native, only on IOS
I am building an instagram like scrolling videos feature for an app. It was working few days back. But now i am getting an error "Maximum update depth exceeded". But the issue is i am only getting this error on ios. On android everything still works fine. I can't seem to figure out what is the issue. I have checked for any looping setState inside useEffect but everything looks fine to me.
This is my main Explore.tsx file where i place my Flashlist to render the scrolling videos.
import { BackHeader, ExplorePost } from '@src/components';
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { FlashList } from '@shopify/flash-list';
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import { useGetExplorePosts } from '@src/hooks/services/exploreService';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { StoreType } from '@src/redux/store';

function Explore(): React.JSX.Element {
  const dimensions = useWindowDimensions();
  const [currentPostId, setCurrentPostId] = useState(0);
  const user: any = useSelector((store: StoreType) => store.user.user);
  const { data, fetchNextPage } = useGetExplorePosts(user?.id);

  const explorePosts = useMemo(() => {
    return data?.pages.reduce((acc, page) => {
      return [...acc, ...page];
    }, []);
  }, [data]);

  const onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems }: any) => {
    console.log('VIEWABLE ITEMS', viewableItems);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCurrentPostId(viewableItems[0]?.item?.post_id);
    }, 0);
  };

  const onEndReached = () => {
    if (!explorePosts) {
      return;
    }
    fetchNextPage();
  };

  const _item = (props: any) => {
    return <ExplorePost {...props} />;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          zIndex: 2,
          marginLeft: 10,
        }}>
        <BackHeader />
      </SafeAreaView>
      <FlashList
        data={explorePosts}
        renderItem={_item}
        estimatedItemSize={dimensions.height}
        snapToAlignment="start"
        decelerationRate="fast"
        pagingEnabled
        extraData={{ currentPostId }}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
        viewabilityConfig={{
          itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 95,
        }}
        onEndReached={onEndReached}
        onEndReachedThreshold={1}
        snapToInterval={dimensions.height}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default Explore;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});


as you can see i set onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged} and this function sets the id of the item which is currently in view and i pass this currentPostId as extraData to be fetched in each item.
In my file ExplorePost.tsx im fetching the data as
const { item, extraData } = props;
const { currentPostId } = extraData;

and based on this currentPostId im playing or pausing the video.
useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentPostId) {
      return;
    }
    if (currentPostId === item?.post_id) {
      _resume();
      return;
    }

    _pause();
  }, [currentPostId]);


I want to automatically play the video which is visible and pause the rest.

here are _resume() and _pause() functions.
const _resume = () => {
  videoRef.current?.resume(); // ERROR GOES AWAY IF I COMMENT THIS LINE 
  setPlaybackState('playing');
};

const _pause = () => {
  videoRef.current?.pause();
  setPlaybackState('paused');
};

The error goes away if i comment this line but it is required to resume the videos. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. This module was working fine few days back and i haven't touched it until now.
Thanks for helping out.
